# Adding this many-many statement to my statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a many-many statement but I am having problems with it.
I'm trying to attach multiple *music styles* to an event, put them in one row, and separate them with a comma.

This is the code I now have:

```
SELECT a.* FROM music_types AS a, events_music_types AS b WHERE a.id == b.music_type_id AND b.event_id == events.ID
```

I'm trying to attach it to what I have now:

```
SELECT
    events.EVENT_NAME, events.start_datetime, events.end_datetime, events.VENUE_LOCATION, events.PARTY_TYPE, events.IMAGE_URL, events.ENTRANCE_PRICE, 
    venues.VENUE_NAME, venues.BEER_PRICE, venues.WINE_PRICE, SPIRITS_PRICE, 
    party_types.PARTYTYPE
FROM events
INNER JOIN venues 
    ON events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID
INNER JOIN party_types
    ON events.PARTY_TYPE = party_types.ID
WHERE start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED'
AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED'
```

And I made it into this:

```
SELECT
    events.EVENT_NAME, events.start_datetime, events.end_datetime, events.VENUE_LOCATION, events.PARTY_TYPE, events.IMAGE_URL, events.ENTRANCE_PRICE, 
    venues.VENUE_NAME, venues.BEER_PRICE, venues.WINE_PRICE, SPIRITS_PRICE, 
    party_types.PARTYTYPE, 
    a.*
FROM events
INNER JOIN venues 
    ON events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID
INNER JOIN party_types
    ON events.PARTY_TYPE = party_types.ID
INNER JOIN music_types AS a, events_music_types AS b
WHERE start_datetime >= '$DATE_START_SELECTED'
AND end_datetime < '$DATE_END_SELECTED' 
AND a.id == b.music_type_id 
AND b.event_id == events.ID
```

And got this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '== b.music_type_id AND b.event_id == events.ID' at line 14

To be honest, I'm not even sure how I should echo this and split it into commas, can you help me out please? Thanks a lot! :)

PS. I added a little visual interpretation of what the relation looks like.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equal to comparisons are incorrect:

```
AND a.id == b.music_type_id
```

Should be:

```
AND a.id = b.music_type_id
```

Comment: Wow, it works! Now which row should I echo and how would I go about separating them with commas? I will in the meanwhile be trying to solve this on my own but if you happen to know please let me know :)

Comment: At this moment, what happened is that because I have attached 2 music styles to this one event, I get the same event printed twice

Comment: Actually, I will post this as a separate question. Thanks again!